How to Check if Metadata Exists Before Adding Section to Post on WordPress
I'm trying to add new post meta via my theme's meta.php file.
How do I set an if statement so that it only adds the meta if the post has meta_key "custom_meta" saved to it?
Here's the code in my theme:
<?php if ( 'extra-meta' === $section ) { ?>

            <li><?php echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_meta', true ) ); ?></li>

<?php } ?>

I tried adding the following to the if statement but it doesn't seem to work:
if ( 'extra-meta' === $section && metadata_exists('post', '$post_id', 'custom_meta')

Or do I need to create another if and elseif statement after the initial if statement?

You have $post_id wrapped in single quotes in your condition. Single quotes are for string literals, and interpolation won't work. Remove them.

Looks like I was over complicated this. I just needed to use this... && get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ocean_review_author', true )
